# Prove that the following series is divergent, $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin n|}{n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, divergent-series

I really do not how to attack this problem.

Comment: A way to do it is to use $|\sin (n) |\ge \sin^2(n) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos(2n)$. Using the divergence of $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ and the convergence of $\sum \frac{\cos(2n)}{n}$, you can conclude

Comment: Another way is to note that among any four consecutive integers, there is at least one with $\lvert \sin n\rvert \geqslant 1/2$. Thus you have a lower bound for the partial sums in terms of harmonic numbers.

Comment: I added an answer based on Daniel Fischer comment in the link marked as duplicated.